# Laravel Eloquent scope for Model A with more recent latest Model B

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-5.7

I have model Foo with related Bar, with related Baz, in Laravel 5.7

Foo has a belongsTo(Bar) relationship

Bar has a hasOne(Baz)->latest() latestBaz relationship

```
   public function latestBaz {
      return $this->hasOne(Baz::class)->latest();
   }
```

I'm trying to create a scope that will get me all Foos where the **latest** Baz was more recently updated.
So where Foo->updated_at is before Foo->Bar->latestBaz->updated_at

I've tried passing $this->updated_at to a whereHas() closure, no luck because ->updated_at doesn't exist at that point, and I've tried the following join

```
/**
 * @param  \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder $query
 * @return mixed
 */
public function scopeOutOfDate($query) {
    return $query->select('foo.*')->whereHas('Bar')
        ->join('foo', function($join) { /** @var JoinClause $join */
            return $join->on('foo.bar_id', '=', 'baz.bar_id')
                ->whereRaw('foo.updated_at > baz.updated_at');
        }
    );
}
```

Which is.... closeish. For each Foo that has a more recent Baz, it has multiple rows. So if a Foo has 5 old Baz and 1 newer Baz, it will fetch 6 rows, and won't let me access related (So Foo[0]->Bar gives null)

Comment: From your join clause, does that mean the relationship from Foo to Bar was a belongsTo? I thought the whole things was a hasManyThrough structure

Comment: Sorry I cannot edit comment, actually the Foo[0]->Bar does return you something, what do you mean by it gives null?

Comment: It's a hasOne. 
`public function latestBaz() { return $this->hasOne(Baz::class)->latest(); }`

Comment: And using the code in the question, Foo[0]->Bar is null. I mean literally it is null, for whatever reason. I use dd($foos), and under relations => Bar, it's "null".

Comment: No I mean from Foo to Bar, is it a belongsTo? At first I thought was a parent to child, child to grandchild relationship, and actually it will return you something, one thing you need to beware is since you use join clause and you didn't rename same columns with same name, it will be overwritten with the later one, so if let says if something like Foo id is overwritten by Bar id thing happens, you will get null, but so far I tried what you did, since you use a select clause to get data from only one table, nothing is overwritten so I did get back my Bar.